# Created new Sharepoint Server Search (2010), but old crawler db is deleted, etc

Tags: crawling

I have successfully created a new Sharepoint Server Search service, however the Server Search Application that previously existed was giving an error that I couldn't seem to resolve.

As a last resort, I'd deleted the Crawler SQL database backend and thought I could maybe re-create this, failing that restore the backup I had just taken.

No such luck however.

So now I'm stuck without being able to get the Search Administration stuck trying to load the Search Application topology (seems stuck) and a crawl status of not able to connect to the administration compomnent.

Can I remove the Search aspect of Sharepoint, and entirely re-create this, perhaps with the install disks ?

Answer (score -2):

Ahh well, I trawled the web for several hours, tried many suggestions from blogs, but then found the answer (Powershell rules !!!).

**1.**
You will find my solution if you reference the following URL and carry out their advice:-

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/sharepoint2010setup/thread/0cec0bac-55c3-431a-b626-e2dd33b8c57e

**2.**

http://blogs.technet.com/b/poojk/archive/2011/11/28/sharepoint-2010-search-service-is-not-able-to-connect-to-administration-component-server.aspx

Comment: in microsoft website you should mark their post as an answer not yours lol